# How populate new ID_MergeTo from operation table ID if MergeFlag is true and MergeTo defined?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have problem I don't know how to solve it. I have two tables Staging and Operation.I create Data Flow Task using SSIS to move data columns  from `Staging([Account_Num],[MergeFlag],[MergeTo],[StartDate],[EndDate])` to `operation([ID],[Account_Num],[MergeFlag],[ID_MergeTo],[StartDate],[EndDate]`. I want to run 2nd data flow task to update `Opreation.[ID_MergeTo]` in Opreation table using OpreationID If the " MergeFlag " is true and If the MergeTo is defined

[image]

my logic with screenshot for 2nd data flow task update ID_MergeTo

### 1- extract data From Staging where " MergeFlag " is true and If the MergeTo is defined sql

```
SELECT        Account_Num, MergeFlag, MergeTo, StartDate, EndDate
FROM            Tmp_SourceTable
WHERE        (MergeFlag = 1) AND (MergeTo IS NOT NULL)
```

### 2- create Lookup use Staging.[Account_Num] and operation.[Account_Num] to get data from 2 tables

[image]

### 3- data view after lookup task

[image]

my Question what task should I use to update opration.[ID_MergeTo] where ID =opration.[ID] update using opration.[ID]

List item

Answer (score 0):

Oledb Command Transformation will help you in updating Operation.[ID_MergeTo].